# How can I measure the time taken by a sqlite3 query?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have an application which writes data to an SQLITE3 database. My application is getting very slow after reaching a point. I want to measure the time specifically taken by a sqlite3_step query per transition. Is there any method to do so? I have already quantified my app and I can see run time is mostly taken by the function using this query. Now I need time per transition.

Thanks
Ruchi

Comment: C++ have an extensive set of [date and time functions and classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: Thanks Joachim, but i am looking one for my query details only. I have used sqlite3_step at other places also but thay are pretty fast.

Answer (score 3):

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is a constant which is declared in `<time.h>`. To get the CPU time used by a task within a C application, use:

```
clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

begin = clock();
/* here, do your time-consuming sqlite query*/
end = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Note that this returns the time as a floating point type. This can be more precise than a second (e.g. you measure 4.52 seconds). Precision depends on the architecture; on modern systems you easily get 10ms or lower, but on older Windows machines (from the Win98 era) it was closer to 60ms.

`clock()` is standard C; it works "everywhere". There are system-specific functions, such as `getrusage()` on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem with SQLITE3, but there is no method available to track the time.

I have tracked the time using the following trick..........

- Create a timer variable before the method execution. (Say startTime = currentTime)
- ................Query SQLITE...............
- After completing the query again take the current time.
- Differentiate the two times to get the execution time.

Hope this will solve your problem.